# Media query not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, media, css-tables

I have been having problem with table not wanting to change (everything else scales as it should) responsively using media queries on iOS, it works perfectly on android phones and tablets, but not on iOS. I have tried adding viewport meta tag, but it doesn't help. Anyone know how to fix it? 
Part of media query that doesn't work:

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
display: block;
max-width:100%; 
 }
th{
display:none;
}

td { 
border: none; 
position: relative;
padding-left: 50%; 
font-size: 1em;
background-color: #F6F7FB;
}

td:before { 
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
left: 6px;
width: 45%; 
padding-right: 10px; 
white-space: nowrap;
line-height: 4em;
vertical-align: middle;
font-weight: bold;
}
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "test"; }
 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "test"; }
 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "test"; }
 td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "test"; }
 td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "test"; }
 td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "test"; }
```

Comment: Check [Bootstrap's Basic Template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) which includes HTML5shiv and Respond.js - maybe this is what you're missing.

Comment: Soo.... Where are the media queries?

Comment: What Evochrome said.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but for me changing display of the  isn't correct. Also the position relative/absolut in tables won't work in most cases. Is it possible for you, to change table structure to divs structure with display table and table-cell? I always do that, when need to make some big table responsive and there is no problem with that

Comment: You are right about tables having problems with the `position` property in many circumstances. But the same problems exist in a div structure with `display: table/row/cell`!

Comment: Yes, totally agree. I thought, that the part of media query is from mobile res, when author want to make table display block, when he will use divs and the style from his question it should work fine